# Django: Django filter queryset for each query in list

Tags: django

I have a list with filter queries. I want to run that queries on django filter queryset.

here its my code

```
    query_list = []
    if len(stream_list) != 0:
        stream_query = reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, [Q(course__stream__contains=word) for word in stream_list])
        query_list.append(stream_query)

    if len(state_list) != 0:
        state_query = reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, [Q(college_name__contains=word) for word in state_list])
        query_list.append(state_query)

    if len(duration_list)!= 0:
        duration_query = reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, [Q(course__program_details__contains=word) for word in duration_list])
        query_list.append(duration_query)
```

now i want to run queries in query_list on django filter queryset

like that

```
clg_list = College.objects.filter(stream_query, state_query, duration_query)
```

how can I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, your `stream`, `state` and `duration` queries are `Q` objects. So you should be able to mix them like this:

```
clg_list = College.objects.filter(reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, query_list))
```