# Django filter queryset __in for *every* item in list (2.0)

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31482723/django-django-filter-queryset-for-each-query-in-list) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618068/django-filter-queryset-in-for-every-item-in-list), but they don't solve my problem because they make a final "count" with a comparison to a number that is hard-coded. I want to make a comparison of a number that is the sum of all ingredients of the recipe itself.

Let's imagine that I have some ingredients in my fridge, with their id's (= array of id's). I want to see what I can cook with that. I have my models like this:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True,
                             default=None)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)


class Unit(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True,
                             default=None)
    abbr = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True,
                            default=None)


class IngredientUnit(models.Model):
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, null=False, blank=True)
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit, null=False, blank=True)
    measurable = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False, blank=True)
    is_int = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False, blank=True)
    value = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=0.0)    


class Recipe(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True,
                             default=None)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(IngredientUnit)
```

I'd like to do this: 'select all recipe that have *all*' the ingredients of an array of ingredient's pk. For example: "Classic Vanilla Cake" has those ingredients: eggs, all-purpose flour, baking powder, baking soda, butter, sugar, vanilla, buttermilk. If one is missing, "Classic Vanilla Cake" shouldn't be in the resulting query. On the contrary, if there are *more* ingredients than those required, "Classic Vanilla Cake" should always be in the resulting query.

So far, I've done this, but it's not working.

```
    ingredient_ids = self.request.POST.getlist('ingredient[]', [])
    if len(ingredient_ids):
        recipes = Recipe.objects\
            .filter(ingredients__in=ingredient_ids)\
            .annotate(nb_ingredients=Count('ingredients'))\
            .filter(nb_ingredients=len(ingredient_ids))
        print([a for a in recipes])
```

The problem is that `nb_ingredients=len(ingredient_ids)` should be `nb_ingredients=the number of the ingredients of the current recipe`

How can I do this?

Comment: Question is not cleat too me yet. You want to get a recipe r with all ingredients(e.g ingredient_ids)?

Comment: I think you just want to put the annotate before the filter, so that each recipe is annotated with the number of ingredients it contains.

Comment: @Sagar I've updated my question: I have some ingredients in my fridge, with their id's (= array of id's). I want to see what I can cook with that. I want to make a comparison of a number that is the sum of all ingredients of the recipe itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! Can't avoid double query but it works like a charm. Here's the solution:

- first, filter on Ingredients that are part of a recipe, for each recipe (= `group by`), *count the total of ingredients found*
- then for all the existing recipes, if the total of ingredient == the total of ingredients founds before, then it's ok, keep it.

It feels like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut (even though the first query filters and eliminates a lot of recipes), but it works, if you have a better solution I'm your man!

```
recipes = Recipe.objects \
    .annotate(found=Count('*'))\
    .filter(ingredients__in=ingredient_ids)
for recipe in recipes:
    a = Recipe.objects.annotate(total=Count('ingredients')).filter(
        pk=recipe.pk, total=recipe.found)
    print("Recipe found:", str(a))
```

And for example, if the ids of the ingredients are `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` you'll get those two queries:

```
SELECT "app_recipe"."id", "app_recipe"."label", "app_recipe"."description",
    COUNT(*) AS "found" FROM "app_recipe"
INNER JOIN "app_recipe_ingredients"
ON ("app_recipe"."id" = "app_recipe_ingredients"."recipe_id")
WHERE "app_recipe_ingredients"."ingredientunit_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
GROUP BY "app_recipe"."id", "app_recipe"."label", "app_recipe"."description";
```

And the second loop will make queries based on the recipes found like this:

```
SELECT "app_recipe"."id", "app_recipe"."label", "app_recipe"."description",
    COUNT("app_recipe_ingredients"."ingredientunit_id") AS "total" 
FROM "app_recipe" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "app_recipe_ingredients" 
ON ("app_recipe"."id" = "app_recipe_ingredients"."recipe_id") 
WHERE "app_recipe"."id" = 1 
GROUP BY "app_recipe"."id", "app_recipe"."label", "app_recipe"."description"
HAVING COUNT("app_recipe_ingredients"."ingredientunit_id") = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to exclude the recipes which have missing ingredients.

```
Recipe.objects.exclude(~Q(ingredients__in=ingredient_ids)).distinct()
```

Tested it, its not working.

In theory, what you want:

> The problem is that nb_ingredients=len(ingredient_ids) should be
>   nb_ingredients=the number of the ingredients of the current recipe

should be achieved with one annotation before the filter and one annotation after the filter (because [the order of annotation and filter matters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses)).

I.e. something like this:

```
recipes = (Recipe.objects
    .annotate(num_ingredients=Count('ingredients'))
    .filter(ingredients__in=ingredient_ids)
    .annotate(found_ingredients=Count('ingredients'))
    .filter(num_ingredients=F('found_ingredients'))
)
```

however when I tested this, it  wasn't working because the ORM didn't reuse the correct JOIN from the filter. This could be some kind of a bug, I just open a [question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/RPU-PnygbLg) in the mailing list.

In case you are using Django 1.11, another approach would be use the new [Subquery-expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions), can you try this.

```
recipes = (Recipe.objects
                .filter(ingredients__in=ingredient_ids)
                .annotate(found_ingredients=Count('ingredients', distinct=True))
                .annotate(num_ingredients=Count(Subquery(
                    Ingredient.objects.filter(recipe=OuterRef('pk')).only('pk')),
                    distinct=True)
                )
                .filter(num_ingredients=F('found_ingredients'))
)
```

Comment: Your latest suggestion is very clever and should work. It doesn't work does it?

Comment: @OlivierPons I think its not working because of a bug. I did some testing now, it works with `ForeignKeys`, but fails with `M2M` fields.

Comment: I just started a new thread on django-users, you can check its progress [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/RPU-PnygbLg).

Comment: Thank you very much for your action I hope this is an actual bug and it will be solved soon!

Comment: @OlivierPons have you tried the `Subquery` approach? Is it working?

Comment: No I didn't try, if you have a Subquery solution may I ask you to post it? And did you try to explode your first suggestion with annotations into 2 subsequents annothation (= execute the first then the second after the first) If it's better than mine I'll check your answer as the right one!

Comment: It's posted, check my answer again :)