# Django exclude queryset __in for *every* item in list

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

This is a bit different from [Django filter queryset __in for *every* item in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618068/django-filter-queryset-in-for-every-item-in-list) and [Django filter queryset __in for *every* item in list (2.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396508/django-filter-queryset-in-for-every-item-in-list-2-0) 
Given the following models:

```
class Product(BaseModel):
    ''' whatever '''

class Customer(BaseModel):
    blacklist = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True)

class Advisory(BaseModel):
    product_names = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
```

Where a customer maintains a list of Products it's not interested in. How can I get a list of the advisories for a given customer?

Let's say I have these in my DB:

```
#   Advisory 1 (should be included as Product 1 isn't in the customers blacklist)
#       product_names
#           Product 1
#           Product 2
#           Product 3
#   Advisory 2 (should be excluded)
#       product_names
#           Product 2
#           Product 3
#   Customer 1
#       blacklist
#           Product 2
#           Product 3
#           Product 4
#           Product 5
```

If I use a queryset like this:

```
queryset = Advisory.objects.all()
blacklist = Customer.blacklist.all()
queryset = queryset.exclude(product_names__in=blacklist).distinct()
```

It will exclude both advisory 1 and advisory 2, as product 2 and 3 are present in the customer blacklist

Comment: So you only want all advisories that have *at least* one `product` that is not in the `blacklist`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Basically what you need here is a `NOT IN` which is apparently lacking in Django. `.exclude` is in fact *not* equal to `NOT IN`, since it means `NOT IN` over the entire relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem by doing it in two steps:

```
# Get the queryset with all advisories
queryset = Advisory.objects.all()
# Find the products the customer doesn't care about
blacklist = Customer.objects.get(pk=customer_id).blacklist.all()
# Build a whitelist of products excluding the blacklist from the customer
whitelist = Product.objects.all().exclude(id__in=blacklist)
# And filter the queryset with the new whitelist
queryset = queryset.filter(product_names__in=whitelist).distinct()
```